# Include Video Playlist on home page

Tags: magento-1.9, home

I like playlist
http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/vnedg

want include playlist to homepage - Who add please tell me. thank you.

```
<figure id="video_player">
  <div id="video_container">
  <video controls poster="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-glacier.jpg">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/glacier.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/glacier.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
</div>
<figcaption>
  <a href="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/glacier.mp4" class="currentvid">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-glacier.jpg" alt="Athabasca Glacier">
  </a>
  <a href="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/lake.mp4">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-lake.jpg" alt="Athabasca Lake">
  </a>
  <a href="http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/mountain.mp4">
    <img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/vid-mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain">
  </a>
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

To Css: styles.css

```
  body { background: #222; }
    #video_player { 
      display: table; line-height: 0;
      font-size: 0; background: #000;
      max-width: 1000px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #video_container { 
      position: relative;
    }
    #video_player div, #video_player figcaption { 
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: top; 
    }
    #video_container video { 
      position: absolute; 
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
    }
    #video_player figcaption { width: 25%; }
    #video_player figcaption a { display: block; }
    #video_player figcaption a { 
      opacity: .5;
      transition: 1s opacity; 
    }
    #video_player figcaption a img, figure video { 
      width: 100%; height: auto; 
    }
    #video_player figcaption a.currentvid, #video_player figcaption a:hover, #video_player figcaption a:focus { opacity: 1; }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
      #video_player video, #video_player figcaption { 
        display: table-row; 
      }
    #video_container { padding-top: 56.25%; }
    #video_player figcaption a { 
      display: inline-block; width: 33.33%; 
    }
    }
```

JS Code

```
var video_player = document.getElementById("video_player");
video = video_player.getElementsByTagName("video")[0],
video_links = video_player.getElementsByTagName("figcaption")[0],
source = video.getElementsByTagName("source"),
link_list = [],
vidDir = "http://demosthenes.info/assets/videos/",
currentVid = 0,
allLnks = video_links.children,
lnkNum = allLnks.length;
video.removeAttribute("controls");
video.removeAttribute("poster");

(function() {
function playVid(index) {
 video_links.children[index].classList.add("currentvid");
    source[1].src = vidDir + link_list[index] + ".webm";  
    source[0].src = vidDir + link_list[index] + ".mp4";
    currentVid = index;
    video.load();
    video.play();
}

for (var i=0; i<lnkNum; i++) {
var filename = allLnks[i].href;
link_list[i] = filename.match(/([^\/]+)(?=\.\w+$)/)[0];
(function(index){
        allLnks[i].onclick = function(i){
        i.preventDefault();  
        for (var i=0; i<lnkNum; i++) {
        allLnks[i].classList.remove("currentvid");
        }
        playVid(index);
        }    
    })(i);
}
video.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    allLnks[currentVid].classList.remove("currentvid");
    if ((currentVid + 1) >= lnkNum) { nextVid = 0 } else { nextVid = currentVid+1 }
    playVid(nextVid);
})

video.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    video.setAttribute("controls","true");
})

video.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    video.removeAttribute("controls");
})

var indexOf = function(needle) {
    if(typeof Array.prototype.indexOf === 'function') {
        indexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;
    } else {
        indexOf = function(needle) {
            var i = -1, index = -1;
            for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                if(this[i] === needle) {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }}
            return index;
        };}
    return indexOf.call(this, needle);
};
    var focusedLink = document.activeElement;
    index = indexOf.call(allLnks, focusedLink);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
if (index) {
    var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
    if (e.keyCode == 40 || e.keyCode == 39) { // down or right cursor
    var nextNode = focusedElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextNode) { nextNode.focus(); } else { video_links.firstElementChild.focus(); }
    }
   if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 37) { // up or left cursor
    var previousNode = focusedElement.previousElementSibling;
    if (previousNode) { previousNode.focus(); } else { video_links.lastElementChild.focus(); }
    }
 }
});

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this pieces of code in static block with identifier 'home' like a  page

example:

```
piece of code html
<style>
piece of code css
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
piece of code js
</script>
```

You have other alternatives to make more 'useful'

example:

1. Insert your html piece code in block static with identifier 'home'
2. Add your css piece code in style.css in your
   skin/package/theme/css/style.css
3. Add your js piece code in any_name.js in your
   skin/package/theme/js/any_name.js

   In the cms home page there is Design(Layout Update XML) use the
   following code in that:

> ```
> <reference name="head">
>   <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/any_name.js</name></action>
> </reference>
> ```

Comment: I tried your method.. video show but video.js not load . I add  code to cms.xml

Comment: Go to block static and click in Design (layout update xml) and put the code referenced, please. Clean cache.